# Cannot find xxx/mysql-server/sql/sql_yacc.h during cmake mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried to learn MySQL source code.

my OS: Manjaro

I have directories like this

```
/mysql-learn
--/mysql-server  // mysql source code clone from gitHub
--/mysql-build   // I created this
```

In `mysql-build` dir ,I execute `cmake ../mysql-server -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=./mysql-boost`

here is the output

```
-- Running cmake version 3.26.3
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.40.0") 
-- CMAKE_MODULE_PATH is /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/cmake
-- MySQL 8.0.33
-- Source directory /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server
-- Binary directory /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-build
-- CMAKE_GENERATOR: Unix Makefiles
-- SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
-- Packaging as: mysql-8.0.33-Linux-x86_64
-- Cannot use lld on this platform
-- Local boost dir /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-build/mysql-boost/boost_1_77_0
-- Local boost zip /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-build/mysql-boost/boost_1_77_0.tar.bz2
-- Found /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-build/mysql-boost/boost_1_77_0/boost/version.hpp 
-- BOOST_VERSION_NUMBER is #define BOOST_VERSION 107700
-- BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-build/mysql-boost/boost_1_77_0
-- ZLIB_VERSION (bundled) is 1.2.13
-- ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/zlib/zlib-1.2.13
-- ZSTD_VERSION (bundled) is 1.5.0
-- ZSTD_INCLUDE_DIR /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/zstd/zstd-1.5.0/lib
-- ZSTD_LEGACY_SUPPORT not defined!
-- OPENSSL_VERSION (system) is 3.0.8
-- The openssl command does not support zlib
-- OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include
-- OPENSSL_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/libssl.so
-- CRYPTO_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/libcrypto.so
-- OPENSSL_LIB_DIR = 
-- OPENSSL_VERSION_MAJOR = 3
-- OPENSSL_VERSION_MINOR = 0
-- OPENSSL_FIX_VERSION = 8
-- SSL_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libssl.so;/usr/lib/libcrypto.so
-- KERBEROS path is none, disabling kerberos support.
-- HAVE_KRB5_KRB5_H  
-- KERBEROS_LIBRARIES  
-- SASL_LIBRARY /usr/lib/libsasl2.so
-- SASL_VERSION (system) is 2.1.28
-- LBER_LIBRARY /usr/lib/liblber.so
-- LDAP_LIBRARY /usr/lib/libldap.so
-- AWK_EXECUTABLE is /usr/bin/gawk
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git  
-- LIBEVENT_VERSION (bundled) 2.1.11
-- LIBEVENT_INCLUDE_DIRS /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/libevent/libevent-2.1.11-stable/include;/home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-build/extra/libevent/libevent-2.1.11-stable/include
-- LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES event_core;event_extra;event_openssl;event_pthreads
-- LZ4_VERSION (bundled) is 1.9.4
-- LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/lz4/lz4-1.9.4/lib
-- ICU_VERSION (bundled) is 69
-- ICU_INCLUDE_DIRS /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/icu/icu-release-69-1/source/common;/home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/icu/icu-release-69-1/source/stubdata;/home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/icu/icu-release-69-1/source/i18n
-- ICU_LIBRARIES icui18n;icuuc;icustubdata
-- PROTOBUF_VERSION (bundled) is 3.19.4
-- PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/protobuf/protobuf-3.19.4/src
-- PROTOBUF_LIBRARY libprotobuf
-- PROTOBUF_LITE_LIBRARY libprotobuf-lite
-- PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE protoc
-- WITH_CURL=none, not using any curl library.
-- RAPIDJSON_INCLUDE_DIR /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/rapidjson/include
-- RAPIDJSON_MAJOR_VERSION is 1
-- RAPIDJSON_MINOR_VERSION is 1
-- UDEV_SYSTEM_LIBRARY /usr/lib/libudev.so
-- FIDO_VERSION (bundled) is 1.8.0
-- FIDO_INCLUDE_DIR /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/extra/libfido2/libfido2-1.8.0/src
-- CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG  -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../../private'
-- CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG  -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../../private'
-- mysys_objlib depends on ext::zlib
-- mysys_objlib depends on ext::zstd
-- clientlib_objlib depends on ext::zlib
-- Found Unix DNS SRV APIs
-- Skipping the LDAP client authentication plugin
-- Skipping FIDO client authentication plugin.
-- Skipping the KERBEROS client authentication plugin.
-- Skipping the OCI authentication client plugin.
-- Library mysqlclient depends on OSLIBS m;/usr/lib/libssl.so;/usr/lib/libcrypto.so
-- MERGE_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARIES TARGET mysqlclient
-- MERGE_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARIES LIBS clientlib;mytime;strings;vio;mysys;zlib;zstd
-- Building ndbcluster plugin
-- Excluding Cluster Java components
-- ndbgeneral_objlib depends on ext::zlib
-- ndbapi_objlib depends on ext::zlib
-- LIBS_TO_MERGE mysys;mytime;ndbapi;ndbgeneral;ndblogger;ndbmgmapi;ndbmgmcommon;ndbportlib;ndbsignaldata;ndbtrace;ndbtransport;strings;zlib
-- Library ndbclient_static depends on OSLIBS m;/usr/lib/libssl.so;/usr/lib/libcrypto.so
-- MERGE_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARIES TARGET ndbclient_static
-- MERGE_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARIES LIBS mysys;mytime;ndbapi;ndbgeneral;ndblogger;ndbmgmapi;ndbmgmcommon;ndbportlib;ndbsignaldata;ndbtrace;ndbtransport;strings;zlib
-- RPC_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/include/tirpc
-- MYSQLX - Text log of protobuf messages enabled
-- MYSQLX - Enabled debug traces
-- json_client_library_objlib depends on ext::zlib
-- Library json_binlog_static depends on OSLIBS m;/usr/lib/libssl.so;/usr/lib/libcrypto.so
-- MERGE_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARIES TARGET json_binlog_static
-- MERGE_CONVENIENCE_LIBRARIES LIBS json_client_library;mysys;mytime;strings
-- LINK_FLAGS for mysqld  -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib/private'
CMake Error at sql/CMakeLists.txt:1294 (MESSAGE):
  Cannot find /home/siyu/software/mysql-learn/mysql-server/sql/sql_yacc.h


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I don't know what happened. Is this problem related to bison? I have installed bison already
[image]

I am expecting cmake finished with no error

Comment: Hey, did you figure out on what to do?

Comment: @piepi hello, I haven't solve the problem. Thers is 1 answer below. you can try it. I haven't try it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to fix this, as I'd found a similar problem, with the following:

`sudo apt install dpkg-dev`

Answer (score 0):

works for me

```
apt install build-essential cmake bison libncurses5-dev libssl-dev pkg-config
apt-get install -y libtirpc-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

delete the build folder and recreate an empty build folder and retry.